# Invoke a method only once from a class

Tags: c++, algorithm, events, logic

I have a shape class in which there is a method (`hitTest(int,int)`) that continuously checks if the mouse is inside its bounds or not. In another method, I keep on checking if the mouse has stayed there for more than 1 sec.
If it has, trigger a function (by notification/event) that runs animation
It it has not, then don't trigger the animation
If it has already triggered the animation and the animation is running but the mouse leaves the area during this, trigger an interrupt function (by notification/event)

```
//OnLoad _initHover = false;

void update() //called continously in the application per frame
{
if(hitTest(getMouseX(), getMouseY())){
                if(!_initHover){
                    _initHover = true;
                    _hoverStartTime = getCurrentTime(); //start hover time
                    cout<<"Start hist test\n";
                }

                //If it has hovered over the video for 1.0 sec
                if((ofGetElapsedTimef() - _hoverStartTime) > 1.0){
                    cout<<"Hitting continously for 1 sec\n";
                    notificationCenter->postNotification(new AnimationStartNotification);
                }
            }
            else{
                    _initHover = false;
                    notificationCenter->postNotification(new AnimationInterruptNotification);
            }
}
```

The above code runs fine but there's a logical issue I am facing while trying to use. There are multiple instances of the above Shape class and each class consequently has their `update()` method as well. The mouse cursor has which has `animationStarthandler` and `animationStophandlers` is a single class in the whole application.

**Issue 1:** So, even when one of the shape just notifies the `animationStarthandler` to fire, the other shape classes on which hit test is false set the animation to `interrupt` and the animation does not run.
**Issue 2:** When the hit test succeeds and the cursor has been in the area for more than `1 sec`, the hit test will keep on sending the notification to start the animation (anim's duration 1.5 sec approx.) How do I restrict the hit test to fire the animation only once and keep on firing the same animation again and again?

If in the main method of my application, I directly try to fire the animation by calling the method `playAnimation` in the pointer class, I get the required result. But I want to give this hover timing and animation functionality to the ShapeClass itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this mean each `Shape` class has a separate timer? Common practice when doing animations is to have a **single timer** which keeps track of overall fps and invokes all redraws simultaneously. Also, I don't see a reason to poll the `Update` method at all. You should simply handle `MouseMove`, `MouseEnter` and other mouse events and call `Update` from there, while a separate (single) timer renders all shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should consider adding a new boolean, which holds the information of the triggering of the animation (called in the code sample `_animationTriggered`). This prevents shapes that have not triggered the animation to stop it and the animation that triggered it to make it several times.

```
if(hitTest(getMouseX(), getMouseY()))
{
    if(!_initHover)
    {
        _initHover = true;
        _hoverStartTime = getCurrentTime();
        cout<<"Start hist test\n";
    }

    if((ofGetElapsedTimef() - _hoverStartTime) > 1.0)
    {
        if (!_animationTriggered)
        {
            cout<<"Hitting continously for 1 sec\n";
            notificationCenter->postNotification(new AnimationStartNotification);
            _animationTriggered = true;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if ( _animationTriggered )
    {
        _initHover = false;
        notificationCenter->postNotification(new AnimationInterruptNotification);
        _animationTriggered = false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to initialie this new boolean in the same place as `_initHover`

Comment: Minor comment: When checking to start the animation, I would first check the boolean and only after that the time. It is a micro-optimisation, but can make a difference in a frequently called routine (and it does not affect readability/maintainability in any way).

Comment: Cool! This works. But there's a certain glitch. The animation runs once and the next time I try to do hit test and get the animation on any other shape, the animation does not run. I'll check back in my code to see if there's something that I am doing wrong

Comment: Strange indeed. You could try to fire the animation from the pointer class (from your question) sequencially on different shapes and see if this works. That could help understanding where is the bug.